Gracefully kill child process started via bash read statement
I have a bash process such as below which reads data using a pipe | read
#!/bin/bash

# Create a file with some data
echo "Name,Age" > data.csv
echo "John,17" >> data.csv
echo "Jane,18" >> data.csv

# Read the file line by line and print the columns
cat data.csv | while read line; do
  name=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 1)
  age=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 2)
  echo "Name: $name, Age: $age"
  sleep 300 # Sleep to ease debugging
done

Run this process:
$ sh dataprint.sh

Now if we run ps command, we can see two process running: a parent and child for | read
  $ ps -aef | grep dataprint.sh | grep -v grep
    501  6705 71492   0 11:33PM ttys000    0:00.01 sh dataprint.sh
    501  6707  6705   0 11:33PM ttys000    0:00.00 sh dataprint.sh

When I attempt to kill the child process, the parent process also dies and (interestingly) prints the code as output.
Why does this happen and how to avoid this?
Here is the full output:
$ sh dataprint.sh &
[1] 6875
$ Name: Name, Age: Age

$ ps -aef | grep dataprint.sh | grep -v grep
  501  6875 71492   0 11:37PM ttys000    0:00.01 sh dataprint.sh
  501  6877  6875   0 11:37PM ttys000    0:00.00 sh dataprint.sh
$
$ kill 6877
$ dataprint.sh: line 14:  6876 Done                    cat data.csv
      6877 Terminated: 15          | while read line; do
    name=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 1); age=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 2); echo "Name: $name, Age: $age"; sleep 300;
done

[1]+  Exit 143                sh dataprint.sh


Which version of bash to your use?

I am running this on a Mac but I am trying to fix the issue for software running on various linux versions. So I would like this to be independent of bash version. But I am not sure if this is caused by specific bash version. Anyway the bash version on Mac is 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin24). I see similar behavior on Linux

I cannot reproduce it with version 5.0.17 and 3.2.57 (both with Linux).

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

See BashFAQ/119 - What's the difference between "cmd < file" and "cat file | cmd"? What is a UUOC?.

sh is not bash -- even when it's a link to the same executable. sh scriptname does not run your script with bash and is not the proper way to run a bash script. (Part of why bash folks frown on ending script names with .sh is that doing so encourages this misunderstanding).

(also, it's not | read that's creating your extra process -- it's | while, which would do the same thing even if you didn't use read at all; any pipeline component that doesn't consist only of a simple external command the shell can execve to replace its child with will have that effect).

I believed until now that in modern systems bash executable is just renamed to sh. Just checked my mac and sure enough sh and bash are separate executables with much different file sizes. Thanks!

@Amol, even when it's the same executable, bash looks at the name it was started under and runs in compatibility mode (turning off some of its features) when started under the name sh.

@Philippe already answered your question but let's clean up your code.
To be more robust, efficient, and maintainable your script should be:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create a file with some data
cat << '!' > data.csv
Name,Age
John,17
Jane,18
!

# Read the file line by line and print the columns
while IFS=, read name age; do
  printf 'Name: %s, Age: %s\n' "$name" "$age"
  sleep 300 # Sleep to ease debugging
done < data.csv

You're running your script with sh, not bash. The shebang is ignored when you specifically invoke a shell when calling it. Even if you have sh aliased to bash, the shell won't behave as normal bash would, it'll try to emulate how sh behaves. To use the shebang just call your script as:
./dataprint.sh

Your ps command doesn't need multiple greps, it should just be:
ps -aef | grep '[d]ataprint.sh'


The shebang is ignored when you specifically invoke a shell when calling it. Even if you have sh aliased to bash, the shell won't behave as normal bash would, it'll try to emulate how sh behaves
This is great info, was not aware of this. Thanks!

The parent process didn't die, it finished normally as its child process died.
As for the code printing, you can avoid it by using bash:
bash dataprint.sh &

